# Managing user progression through a form with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a very long horizontal form that is separated into multiple sub-forms, acting as *slides*.

Only one *slide* is visible at any given time,  however they each have a button that allows going on to the next section, without actually submitting the form. I also would like the user to be able to navigate back so I added buttons that let the user go back and forward. I use the JQuery validate plugin to validate user input.

How do I prevent the user from navigating through the form if the information is in an incorrect state?

Comment: What are the UI requirements for this issue? Screen size, scrolling, etc.

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne the form is scrolling from left to right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the jqQuery validate plugin you can accomplish exactly this, just read up the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), use the valid() function to check the elements in the currently shown sub form.